# Automatically use `.zwc` version of a `source`d file

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

I have come across `*.zwc` files, which I believe are Z-shell Word Code files, or compiled `zsh` script.

When `source`-ing an arbitrary file, is there a way to have `zsh`:

- Use the file's `.zwc` if it exists and is newer than the file
- Else, compile the file to Z-shell Word Code and then `source` it

If I have a file containing only functions, is the answer any different?

There don't seem to be many tutorials around Z-shell Word Code, so feel free to point me at them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in order to use `.zwc` files, you do not have to do anything. As the [section on the `.` command in the Zsh's manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-_002e) states:

> […] If a file named ‘*file*`.zwc`’ is found, is newer than *file*, and is the compiled form (created with the `zcompile` builtin) of *file*, then commands are read from that file instead of *file*.

The same is true for `source`, as it is the same as `.`, except for the search order.

---

Automatically compiling any sourced scripts could be done by creating wrapper functions. For example:

```
source () {
    [[ ! "$1.zwc" -nt $1 ]] || zcompile $1
    builtin source $@
}

. () {
    [[ ! "$1.zwc" -nt $1 ]] || zcompile $1
    builtin . $@
}
```

Of course as these wrappers are very simple and might need some extra fail-saves. For example if the directory, in which the  file to be sourced resides, is not writable. Also, the compilation might fail, even if the the source file  has no syntax errors.

Comment: FYI, I [implemented the checks and also the edge case for a drop-in replacement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455097/143394)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Adaephon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454434/143394), I wrote a complete drop-in replacement of both `source` and `.`.

It wasn't easy because of the builtin behaviour of passing `$@` if no arguments are given.

The required aliases are in the comments.

`compile-source-file`:

```
# This file needs to be `sourced` to ensure a drop-in behaviour for `source` or `.`
# The shell passess "$@" to source if no arguments are given after the file to be sourced.

# Works in bash.

# Required aliases are:
# alias source='builtin source compile-source-file source "$#" "$@"'
# alias      .='builtin .      compile-source-file .      "$#" "$@"'

# zsh: compile functions before sourcing
# This function expects to be called with:
# $1 builtin to use, either `.` or `source`.
# $2 file to source
# $3... arguments to pass to sourced file
function compile_then_source () {
  local method=$1 file=$2; shift 2; local args=("$@")

  # ${var@Q} gives value of var quoted in a format that can be reused as input
  [[ $BASH_VERSION ]] && { eval builtin "$method" "$file" "${args@Q}"; return $?; }

  if [[ ! $file.zwc -nt $file ]]; then
    # Use canonical pathname for zrecompile's happiness
    if [[ -r $file && -w ${file:h} ]]; then zcompile "${file:P}"; fi
  fi

  eval builtin "$method" "$file" "${(q)args[@]}"
}

function main () {
  local use_builtin=$1  # '.' or 'source'
  local num_args=$2     # Number of elements in calling shell's $@, which follow
  shift 2;
  local wrapper_args=("$@")
  wrapper_args=("${wrapper_args[@]:0:$num_args}")
  shift "$num_args"
  local file=$1; shift;

  # Now $@ is the arguments passed after the file to be soured
  if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then # arguments were passed
    use_args=("$@")
  else  # use $@ from the wrapper args
    use_args=("${wrapper_args[@]}")
  fi
  compile_then_source "$use_builtin" "$file" "${use_args[@]}"
}

main "$@"

unset -f main compile_then_source
```